# Can a private NPM repository be used as a CDN?

Tags: node.js, cdn

Can we setup a private NPM repository and CDN via a same plugin/server.

Use case I package my own front end files in say a folder called

```
/NewUI
```

which has `/CSS` and `/JS` folders inside of it.

I create an NPM repo at /NewUI level, and publish it.

I expect the server to be create a sort of CDN/FTP server where It auto generates.

```
http://<IP>:<PORT>/NewUI/CSS/css1.css
```

and so on.

Any pointers regarding approaches, pros and cons, existing code to look at and tweak would be great.